# What does negative value means for TTL in JMS config file?

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have config file of JMS, I am facing issue with connection pooling.when i looked in config file of weblogic server i found negative value for TTL.could anyone please explain what it means.

```
<queue name="UXFLogQueue">
    <sub-deployment-name>application</sub-deployment-name>
    <delivery-params-overrides>
      <delivery-mode>Persistent</delivery-mode>
      <time-to-live>-1</time-to-live>
      <priority>-1</priority>
      <redelivery-delay>-1</redelivery-delay>
    </delivery-params-overrides>
    <delivery-failure-params>
      <redelivery-limit>1</redelivery-limit>
    </delivery-failure-params>
    <jndi-name>UXFLogQueue</jndi-name>
  </queue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If no JMS template is specified for this destination, then -1 means that the destination will not override the TimeToLive setting. Otherwise, -1 means that the value comes from the template."

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jmsqueue_config_overrides.html#1104829